# What does the term data dependent kernel mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology, kernel-trick

I was reading [a paper that revisits (singled layered) Radial Basis Function networks](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v51/que16-supp.pdf). In they claim that they show that RBF methods can be recast as "certain data-dependent kernels". I was wondering what this term meant.

A quick google search drove me to two research papers, one titled [Data-Dependent Kernels for High-Dimensional Data Classification](https://www.cse.ust.hk/~jamesk/papers/ijcnn05c.pdf) and another titled [Learning Eigenfunctions Links Spectral Embedding and Kernel PCA](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/bengio_eigenfunctions_nc_2004.pdf). One is not to long, 6 pages, and the other (considered the "original" place Data Dependent Kernels where introduced) is 33 pages. After 10ish years I'd assume there might be a concise or simple explanation of what Data Dependent kernels mean. Is there a simple explanation of this apart from trying to parse two dense machine learning research papers?

Comment: This strikes me as merely an application of locally adaptive smoothing. That is, the local characteristics of the data determines whether the features will tolerate higher smoothing, if statistically similar, and less broad smoothing near regions of rapidly changing features. An imaging application of this would be the [Pixon method](http://www.adass.org/adass/proceedings/adass98/puetterrc/).